# Alterar permissão de usuário do Moodle

Tags: moodle

Como alterar a permissão de um usuário comum para um usuário administrador no Moodle3.3 através de comandos SQL.

Answer (score 1):

A função de administrador do site tem permissão para fazer qualquer coisa no Moodle, então use com cautela.

Você precisará conhecer o ID do usuário primeiro - então recupere o id da tabela

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_user
Then add the id to the value column here

SELECT *
FROM mdl_config
WHERE name = 'siteadmins'
For example

UPDATE mdl_config
SET value = value || ',3'
WHERE name = 'siteadmins'
```

Você provavelmente precisará sair e voltar novamente para que isso possa afetar.

Isso só funciona para administradores do site. Para outras funções, você precisa fazer o login como administrador e ir para site admin -> users -> permissions

Comment: Tinha excluído todos os usuários da base de dados do Moodle.

Não existe um usuário administrador na base de dados.

Então criei um usuário e consigo logar, mas queria colocar permissão de administrador. Os comandos não funcionaram, teria outra forma de tornar esse usuário um administrador do sistema?

Comment: É meio estranho não funcionarem, qual erro o que acontece ?

Comment: Na verdade não dar nenhum erro e ao realizar o login novamente é exibido a visão de usuário comum.

Comment: Alguma possibilidade de ter sido alterado o grupo de admin > "siteadmins" ?

Comment: Criei o usuário através do comando abaixo. Já teria como criar o usuário administrador direto por comando sql?

INSERT INTO mdl_user (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,confirmed,description, mnethostid) VALUES ('admin','cidade','admin@gmail.com','admin',MD5('teste'),1,'Ambiente de teste',1);

Comment: Bom confirmando que executou os comandos certinho ... no select você pega no id do seu usuário para adicionar no update, você fez isto ? @EzequiasSilva

Comment: Sim. Fiz exatamente como mandam os comandos. Estou utilizando Moodle3.3. Isso influencia?

Comment: Teria de ver se tem alguma tabela de roles algo assim

Comment: Não estou no trabalho agora. Amanhã te retorno. Já vasculhei pela net e não encontrei nada disso. Sua ajuda vai ser muito bem vinda.

Comment: Então, na tabela mdl_role tem isso: 
id: 1  
shortname: manager
Sortorder: 1
archetype: manager

Comment: Tenho também a tabela mdl_role_allow_assign com id, roleid e allowassign. Não vejo nenhuma relação com o id de usuário. Peço compreensão pela ignorância.